# com_redirect is timing out (resetting list limit)

Tags: joomla-3.x, redirect

I was using com_redirect showing 100 items, when I changed it to "all," the list is too large and it times out. How can I get back to the list of 100 without uninstalling the component?

Comment: do you have acces to your database?

Comment: I have a backup file on the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to Global Configuration, make sure Default List Limit is set to 20-30.
Log Out from admin, Restart browser. Then Log In again and any list will be set to List Limit.

Comment: You 're welcome :-)